# Relocate "gwt-unitCache" directory

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

GWT will generated a `gwt-unitCache` directory with some cache files. After couple of days of working, the directory might produce over 1GB cache files. I am afraid to generate these files might damage my SSD harddisk.

I have created a 2GB ramdisk for storing temp files. My question is if it is possible to relocate the `gwt-unitCache` directory?

Comment: You can temporarily disable the persistent unit cache with -Dgwt.persistentunitcache=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `'<sysproperty key="gwt.persistentunitcachedir" value="cache_dir"/>'` to the gwtc task in `build.xml`

*I tried to use ${env.TEMP} instead of pointing to a physical path, but saw some random IO issues of java.*

--OR--

Add `'<sysproperty key="gwt.persistentunitcache" value="false"/>'` to the gwtc task in `build.xml`

*Disable create any cache files, which this is a little bit slower*.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a maven project you can change the location like this:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>

 <configuration>
   <persistentunitcachedir>yourlocation</persistentunitcachedir>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```